# cmake dependency between two projects at the same level

Tags: cmake, dependencies

In my CMake project I have two 3rd party libraries which are required.
The problem is that the second one requires the first one to be build first.

To be precise I have the following structure

```
   -project
      CMakeLists.txt // add_subdirectory(first_lib)
                     // add_subdirectory(second_lib)
      - first_lib
           CMakeLists.txt // ...
      - second_lib
           CMakeLists.txt // ..
                          // contains find_package(first_lib REQUIRED)
                          // ..
```

This project cannot build because the first library must be build first and installed to make available its package.

What's the best way to deal with this case in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

You can make *second_lib* depend on target name of *first_lib*. This will force *first_lib* to be build first.

To avoid modification of CMakeLists.txt of *second_lib* you can use the following solution:

Create a custom Findfirst_lib.cmake module. Set any *first_lib*-related variables expected by *second_lib* inside the module.

```
set(FIRST_LIB_LIBRARIES first_lib) #use *first_lib* target name here.
set(FIRST_LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/first_lib/include)
```

Do not forget to add the module's directory to [CMAKE_MODULE_PATH](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.html).

This solution assumes that *second_lib* uses the variables, set by Findfist_lib module, in target_link_libraries, target_include_directories etc. Like:

```
target_link_libraries(second_lib ${FIRST_LIB_LIBRARIES})
```

I have not found a way to make it work with imported targets.

Comment: hi ptrlukar, I found the answer and I post it. Works pretty well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answere here using

```
add_dependencies()
```

[Force building external project (with buildtools) before main project with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735628/force-building-external-project-with-buildtools-before-main-project-with-cmake)

Comment: Yes, that is surely easier way to force build order. But will find_package(first_lib) actually find anything? first_lib is not installed before second_lib building begins.

Comment: @ptrlukas unfortunately now. I've just found that there was an issue when I build that made me believe that tmy issue was sorted out. The question is still open I am afraid.